# after updating the chrome version and chrome driver version to 80, getting inspector detached event error

Tags: protractor

Below is the error message I am getting. When the browser is opening and while the page is loading, it fails with the error. I am running it using protractor with javascript. This was working fine until last week in chrome and chrome driver version 79

Protractor version 5.4.2, I am using

> Error message:
>
> Failed: disconnected: received Inspector.detached event
>         (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.87)
>       Build info: version: '', revision: '', time: ''
>       System info: host: '', ip: '', os.name: '',java.version: ''
>       Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Comment: are you sure you successfully updated the chromedriver? I can assume the problem is that it doesn't see your driver - `driver.version: unknown`

Comment: I would suggest cleaning node_modules and reinstalling chromedriver, I know it's not the most elegant but it will most likely work.

Comment: Tried in firefox it works fine. But in firefox I am getting "Failed: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined". This is happening for a button click, upon click it opens a new tab. After the new tab opens it immediately fails with error. this is my code.    browser.element(by.buttonText('Launch')).click()
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
          browser.switchTo().window(handles[1])
         browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true).then(function () {
                browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.buttonText("Get started")), 90000))
            })